# Can't find latest NVIDIA Propietary Drivers

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, additional-drivers

I'm trying to update my Nvidia drivers to 361.15 Proprietary (Prime) but it keep showing me the open source (Nouveau) drivers of it and I can't find the prime version of it. I tried manually installing it but it was confusing. The PPA i'm using is  launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. So if anyone can please help me I would greatly appreciated it.

[Drivers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9qRm.png)

[List of my PPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQXo.png)

Comment: Why does 364.15 not work for you?

Comment: I can't find the proprietary version of 364.15. I  don't want to use the open source version of 364.15, I just want to use the proprietary version. I'm currently using 352.63 proprietary version.

Comment: open source does not mean it is Nouveau. Every graphics driver from that PPA is open source. They aren't generic, you just have legal access to their code.

Comment: I also don't want to use the Nouveau version, just the prime version.  If I install that driver it will say that I am not using a restricted driver.

Comment: I'm using a driver from the PPA right now and PRIME works for me. They aren't official NVIDIA drivers, but they work just as well, and have the same features. Open Source is not the same thing as Generic.

Comment: Sorry for not listening to you. I'm relearning how to use Linux.

Comment: I've experienced worse here. You were skeptical. Some people are outright rude

Comment: Thanks. I was trying not to be rude. When I applied that driver, it mess up my intel card. I decided just to stick drivers that are approved by Ubuntu.  Even is the drivers are the latest, it can still mess up. I'm just glad the latest driver is offical by Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Source doesn't mean generic.

Every driver from that PPA is open source, but each one will work just as well as the proprietary driver.

Nouveau is the only generic driver there.

Open Source means you or anyone else can easily review the code that went into making the driver, and even use it to build your own version of the driver.

Proprietary means the code is not available to review or edit.

Generic drivers are made to work with a certain brand or category of device, but aren't optimized or anything to provide any sort of performance.

Comment: I'm gonna try a benchmark to see if that driver gives me the same or better performance.

Comment: @cartoon49 You seem to be, here and in comments above, insisting that Zacharee1 is wrong and open source means nouveau, it does not, he is right, it simply means the code is available for review.

Comment: Your right and just added this driver on ubuntu 16.04.